# Creating a menu inside a tabbed modal dialog (overlay)

Tags: javascript, css, overlay, modal-dialog

I am going to create a form inside of a tabbed modal dialog (aka modal window, aka overlay).  I am wondering which library would be best for this, if one exists at all.  It is important that the dialog box have tabs.  If there is a great library for creating modal dialogs without tabs but provides an easy way to add tabs, please do suggest that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/) will do what you want.  A bit of learning involved though.  Worth the effort if you ask me.  I'm sure jquery easily allows you to do the same also.